# Замена текста js заглавная буква

Tags: javascript

**HTML**

```
<div class="gold" id="text1">
    <ul>
        <li>Тест1~~Тест2~~Тест3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="gold" id="text1">
    <ul>
        <li>Тест1~~Тест2~~Тест3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gold');

for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var el = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("li");
    var listItemContent = el[0].textContent;

    el[0].innerHTML = listItemContent.split("~~").join("</li><li>");
}
```

Как сделать чтоб заглавная буква шла с новой строчки?

Тест1

Тест2

Тест3

но не во всех строчках есть ~~, единственное что есть это заглавная буква

Comment: Где здесь заглавная буква?

Comment: Какая заглавная буква?

Comment: забыл, поправил

Comment: Покажите, какой html  в итоге хотите получить

Comment: <li>Тест1</li> <li>Тест2</li> <li>Тест3</li>, но не во всех строчках есть ~~, единственное что есть это заглавная буква

Comment: Так замените "~~" на "</li><li>"

Comment: Здравствуйте **@Never3D**! `но не во всех строчках есть ~~, единственное что есть это заглавная буква` Приведите пример этих строк. В вашем примере везде есть `~~`. Описание задания считаю неполным и непонятным, поставил минус, как улучшите/отредактируете вопрос, с радостью минус уберу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере один `li` оказывается в другом `li`. Возможно в этом у вас проблема? Если да, вот мой вариант:

```js
'use strict';

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gold');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var ul = elements[i].querySelector('ul');
  var li = ul.querySelector("li");
  var liTextContent = li.textContent;

  ul.removeChild(li);
  var arrayContent = liTextContent.split("~~");

  for (var a = 0; a < arrayContent.length; a++) {
    var newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.textContent = arrayContent[a];
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="gold" id="text1">
    <ul>
      <li>Тест1~~Тест2~~Тест3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="gold" id="text1">
    <ul>
      <li>Тест1~~Тест2~~Тест3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Если что-то другое вам требуется, опишите задание более полно.